# Is $A^n \rightarrow \mathbb 0$ equivalent to "magnitude of each Eigenvalue of $A$ is $<1$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Exercise 4 after $\S$ 91 from Paul R. Halmos's *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces* (second edition) invites to prove or disprove the following assertion.

> If $A$ is a linear transformation (operator) on a finite-dimensional unitary space, then a necessary and sufficient condition that $A^n \rightarrow \mathbb 0$ is that all the proper values (Eigenvalues) of $A$ be (strictly) less than $1$ in absolute value.

For reference, $\S 91$ of the book identifies the symbolic expression $\Vert A_n - A \Vert \rightarrow \mathbb 0$ with the verbal assertion that "a sequence $(A_n)$ of linear transformations converges to a fixed linear transformation $A$". Also, $\S 88$ of the book defines the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ of a linear transformation by writing $\Vert A \Vert = \sup\limits_{x \in \mathcal V}\big\{\Vert Ax \Vert : \Vert x \Vert = 1\big\}$ where $A$ is defined on an inner product space $\mathcal V$.

---

I am able to prove the necessity (hopefully correctly), but stalled with the sufficiency and would appreciate help.

**Proof for the necessity:** Let $\mathcal V$ be the unitary space in question, let $m$ be the dimension of $\mathcal V$, and let $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_m$ be the Eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct) of $A$. It is clear that from a consideration of the triangular form of $A$ w.r.t. a suitable basis in $\mathcal V$ that $\lambda_1^n, \cdots, \lambda_m^n$ are the Eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct) of $A^n$. If $A^n \rightarrow \mathbb 0$ (operator), then we have $\left\Vert A^n \right\Vert \rightarrow 0$ (scalar). Because the magnitude of an Eigenvalue of a linear transformation $B$ is less than or equal to the norm of $B$, we see that $\left\vert \lambda_i^n \right\vert \leq \left\Vert A^n \right\Vert$ for $i = 1, \cdots, m$. It follows that $\left\vert \lambda_i^n \right\vert \rightarrow 0$ which leads to that $\left\vert \lambda_i \right\vert \leq 1$.

**Unsuccessful attempt for the sufficiency:** In addition to the hypothesis of the above proof, let $\left\vert \lambda_i \right\vert \leq 1$ for $i = 1, \cdots, m$. A consideration of the triangular form of $A$ w.r.t. a suitable basis in $\mathcal V$ reveals that $A^n \rightarrow N$ where each Eigenvalue of $N$ is zero. It is clear that $N$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Halmos wrote "**strictly** less than $1$". You cannot change the condition $|\lambda|<1$ to $|\lambda|\le1$. This should be obvious: if $Av=\lambda v\ne0$ with $|\lambda|=1$, then $\|A^kv\|=\|v\|$ for every positive integer $k$; therefore $A^k$ does not converge to zero and so doesn't $A^k$.

Comment: The statement in the block quote is true. For sufficiency, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4308091) to another question.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, it was a mistake to write $\vert \lambda \vert \leq 1$ in the title of the post. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It has been pointed out to me that you are interested in complex operators over complex inner product spaces (I missed the adjective *unitary*), where we consider the full complex spectrum. In this case you can use [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) as done in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303957/schur-stability-without-the-jordan-canonical-form/4308091#4308091) answer to get your sufficient condition.

I shall keep my counterexample for real spaces and spectrums though, as I think it is informative as to why we need to look at the full complex spectrum. Without further restrictions on $A$ this condition is not sufficient for real vector spaces where we only care about real eigenvalues. Set
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\theta$ is some small irrational angle. All this transformation does is rotate vectors around the $z$ axis by $\theta$ and shrink their $z$ component by $1/2$. This means that the only real eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda=1/2<1$, with corresponding normalised eigenvector $v=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^T$. However, for any $n\in \mathbb N$ we have
$$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}\cos n\theta&-\sin n\theta & 0 \\ \sin n\theta & \cos n\theta & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1/2^n\end{pmatrix},$$
which means that $\|A^n\|\geq 1$  for all $n$, because for any nonzero vector $u=(x,y,0)^T$ we have that $\|A^nu\|=\|u\|.$ Thus $A^n$ does not converge to $0$, even though $A$'s only real eigenvalue lives strictly in the unit circle.

This isn't a counterexample to the general statement if we consider all complex eigenvalues of $A$, because $e^{\pm i\theta}$ are complex eigenvalues of $A$ living on the boundary of the unit circle, and hence there is no contradiction.

Comment: The vector space in the problem statement is a **unitary space**, that is, a complex inner product space. Your counterexample doesn't work in this setting.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you! I did not spot this. I shall keep my answer because I quite like it as an example showing why we need to consider the full complex spectrum and not just its real parts. I have edited the post accordingly, and linked to your answer on the other post.