# Convergence in norm with stable asymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

Given a discrete-time stable, **asymmetric** matrix $A$ with maximum eigenvalue strictly less than one in absolute value and a vector $x$, is it necessarily true that $||A^t x|| \leq ||x||$ for all $t\geq 0$?

It is clearly true in the limits, since $A^0 x = x$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} A^t = \mathbf 0$ by stability of $A$. But I am not sure if it is true in general for $ 0 < t < \infty$.

If not, is there another bound on the norm of $A^t x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. E.g. pick any two negative real numbers $a,b\in(-1,0)$. Then
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{a&1\\ 0&b}\pmatrix{0\\ 1}\right\|_2
=\left\|\pmatrix{1\\ b}\right\|_2
>\left\|\pmatrix{0\\ 1}\right\|_2.
$$
That the spectral radius of a matrix is smaller than $1$ doesn’t mean that the operator $2$-norm is smaller than $1$.

Comment: There must be some convenient bound in terms of $||x||$ and $||A||$, no?

Comment: @phil Yes. E.g. there is some constant $C>0$ and some $r$ such that $\rho(A)\le r<1$ and $\|A^kx\|\le Cr^k\|x\|$ for every integer $k\ge0$. However, the constant $C$ can be very large. If you want a practical upper bound to control the size of $\|A^kx\|$, you need to find a more refined one.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Could you point me toward a source for this bound or some materials that might help me understand how to go about refining it? I'm very interested in how something like this would be obtained

Comment: @phil The bound in my previous comment or similar ones can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4308091) and [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4759053). I am not sure which books have intensive discussions on this kind of bounds, but you may try those books on matrix analysis, such as Horn and Johnson’s *Matrix Analysis*, the book with the same title by Bhatia, or Meyer’s *Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra* books. Books on numerical linear algebra may also cover this kind of bounds too.

Comment: thank you! I will check out these resources

Answer (score 2):

The solution of discrete linear dynamical system $x_+ = A x$ is given by the discrete series $x_t = A^t x_0$, for $t \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. Complying with your conditions, the solution converges to zero due stability. The norm is always bounded by $\lVert x_t \lVert = \lVert A^t \lVert \lVert x_0 \lVert \leq \lVert \lambda_+ \lVert^t \lVert x_0 \lVert$ due triangular inequality .

Comment: Thank you. I just was not sure if this was true when $A$ is asymmetric

Comment: This is not a necessary sufficient.

Comment: Would you please approve the answer?

Comment: The matrix norm is an upper bound for the spectral radius, not the other way around. Eigenvalues with multiplicity provide counter-examples.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Does this explain why the answer is correct? Because if $\rho$ is spectral radius, then this would mean that $||Ax||\leq\rho (A) ||x|| \leq ||A|| ||x||$? Or am I understanding your comment incorrectly

Comment: Never mind, there is a counterexample in the other answer

Comment: I said that $\rho(A)\le\|A\|$. There is a theorem that says that for any $\epsilon$ one can find a vector norm so that in the induced operator norm also $\|A\|\le\rho(A)+\epsilon$. But that is not helpful for the claim, as that is wrong if the norms are fixed, not adapted to $A$.

Comment: That said, this is sad. :-( Thanks, @LutzLehmann